# If the real zeroes of real polynomial $p(x,y)$ are disjoint points and curves, is $p(x,y)$ a positive sum of squares?

Tags: polynomials, roots, sum-of-squares-method, multivariate-polynomial

For example, $p(x,y) = x^2(x-1)^2 + y^2(y-1)^2$ has real zeroes in the set $\{(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)\}$ and admits a decomposition into a sum of squares. How can I find decompositions like this ?

Comment: Do you mean it's a disjoint union of only points? Otherwise $x^2+y^2-1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: No, that would not be a counterexample since its zero set is not a disjoint union of multiple curve/points.  I seem to have a very high degree polynomial with a few thousand terms (unfortunately I can't share it here since it so large) that has a zero set that consists of a few different curves, but it doesn't seem to factor.  I suspect it has a decomposition as a positive sum of square.

Comment: Maybe a more general question is: what does it mean when $p(x,y)$ is a real polynomial whose zeroes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a disjoint set?

Comment: You still can get a disconnected real algebraic curve who's not a sum of squares, for example $(x^2+y^2-1)((x-3)^2+y^2-1)$.

Comment: You can also have an exampe with an ireducible polynomial, for example $y^2-x(x-1)(x-2)$.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Elliptic curves seem to be a good thing for me to stare out.

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer, by the way. That was more than helpful.